# Delete many to many duplicates in sql without ID

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to delete duplicates from many to many table via PGADMIN4 tool.

If I am selecting duplicates then the query works fine and returns all duplicates:

```
WITH CTE (organizationsid, manufacturerid, DuplicateCount) AS 
(
    SELECT 
        organizationsid, 
        manufacturerid,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY organizationsid, manufacturerid
                           ORDER BY organizationsid) AS DuplicateCount
    FROM 
        public.manufacturerrelationships
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE DuplicateCount > 1;
```

But if I am trying to replace `SELECT *` with `DELETE` at the end, I get this error:

> ERROR:  relation "cte" does not exist
> LINE 12: FROM CTE
>
> SQL state: 42P01
> Character: 308

The table has only two columns referring to different tables. What is the reason of the error and how could I delete duplicates?

Comment: "CTE" or just use lowercase...

Comment: @madflow I tried FROM "CTE", but sitll same